# How to setup ClamAV and Wazuh in Cloud Server

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, wazuh, clamav

for setup wazuh, im already follow the documentation from here [wazuh clamav](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/capabilities/malware-detection/clam-av-logs-collection.html)
im also update the config as follows

```
LogSyslog true
OnAccessExcludeRootUID yes
```

for testing, im adding new user `user` and set the privilege to be able to download eicar sample viruses here https://secure.eicar.org/eicar.com.txt into `/tmp` folder.

Im activate ClamAV with command

```bash
clamonacc --move=/tmp/quarantine
```

But, then when i run `wget https://secure.eicar.org/eicar.com.txt` with username `user` in folder `/tmp`, the eicar sample vius wont move into `/tmp/quarantine`

Comment: fyi this is off-topic here as it's not a programming question. Seems like more of a product/customer support issue. Also, [su] is for general computing questions (and [ubuntu.se] for Ubuntu-specific questions). Note that the [tag:ubuntu-22.04] tag description explicitly states "GENERAL UBUNTU SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC"

Comment: @DavidMakogon already post to superuser